# Need to adjust line with heading text

Tags: html, css

i am having issue with line with heading when goes to multi line. It will bigger than text visible area.

How can i achieve like this?

```css
.heading-bordered {
  font-size: 32px;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 350px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.heading-bordered span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.heading-bordered span:before{
  height: 2px;
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading-bordered">
  <span>This is so long heading and so long....</span>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: What you want to achieve, can you explain it a bit more clear.?

Comment: if you want to do it then go with `text-align:justify` instead of `text-align:center`. that is the only solution for your desired output.

Comment: the short answer is you cannot ... check the dups for the explanation, you may think they have nothing to do with your question but not .. yout issue is the width or inline-block element

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
.heading-bordered span:before {
    height: 2px;
    background: #333;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 25px;
    right: 25px;
    top: 100%;
}
```

Comment: no no text can be more or less. We can't set statically like this

Comment: I tried with more text the line is equal follow the above code

Comment: try with less content